# Constructor with reference arguments in g++ compiler

Tags: c++

Have a look at the following piece of code

Header File:

```
class CxUser
{ 
public:
    CxUser(string& guid) {} 
};
```

I have a c++ file that instantiates the class using `CxUser(string("xxx-xxx-x-xxxx"))`. But this statement fails to compile in g++ with error "***no matching function for call to CxUser::CxUser(std::string)***" whereas it compiles in VC++. Surprisingly, the following piece of code to instantiate the class works.

```
string guid("xxx-x-xxxx-xxx-xx"); CxUser user(guid);
```

Any help would be appreciated....

Comment: Could you post the error message?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need:

```
class CxUser{ public: CxUser(const string& guid) {} }
```

When you say:

```
CxUser c( "foobar" );   // or whatever
```

a temporary string object is created from the characterv array. In C++ you cannot bind non-const references to temporaries.

Answer (score 2):

You are asking to pass a reference to a string -- essentially a pointer to the location where it is stored.  But when you create the anonymous temporary like that, it isn't stored anywhere --- "there's no there there" -- there's nothing to pass.  By storing it in a named temporary, you give it a location to work with.

When you use a non-const reference as a parameter, you imply that you are going to change the reference, which is non-existant, so you can't change it.   When you use a const reference, the compiler know you can't change it, so it can do some magic so that the anonymous temporary reference parameter works.

Comment: If this were the case, you couldn't call non-const members on a temporary (which receive a pointer to non-const `this`), but you can.

Comment: @Konrad: Are you saying that you can't legally call non-const members on a temporary?

Answer (score 1):

I think if you make the constructor accept a `const std::string&` then the `CxUser(string("xxx-xxx-x-xxxx"))` should work.

Comment: you mean `const std::string &` (of course it works without the reference)

Comment: Well yes.  Anytime you pass a non-POD value you should pass it by either reference or pointer.